# Clarifications of use of Session in Parse Dashboard

Tags: parse-platform

I recently noticed the addition of a "Session" object in Parse dashboard. Now, from what I understand, a session uniquely identifies a user to the server. So why would we need such a Session? For the session token? We already have a currentInstallation... so I don't really see the point. Can someone explain and provide a scenario where I would use the "Session" object. Right now they just annoy me by their presence because they take up potential space on the Parse server and I would like to go delete them all but want to make sure that isn't stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The sessions are used by parse to deal with the users (is the user logged?, on which devices?, etc.), and are available as a class as you may want to manipulate them. By deleting the sessions you would automatically logout all your users, so it's a pretty bad idea.

You don't have to use or touch anything about this class, but here are few examples of why it can be useful:

> [...] If a user contacts you about his or her account being compromised in your app, you can use the Data Browser, REST API, or Cloud Code to forcefully revoke user sessions using the Master Key. These new APIs also allow you build a “session manager” UI screen where your app’s users can see a list of all devices they’ve logged in with, and optionally log out of other devices. [...]

You can read more about the Sessions on their [blog post](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/).